# Git manage a website with some changing content

Tags: git, deployment, web

I develop a website hosted on a dedicated server.The site is working under PHP, there is some self-written CMS which allows, particularly, edit the files under DocumentRoot (e.g. templates and configs).
Now I'd like to manage this site using Git. I've created a bare repo on the server and set up a post-receive hook that copies pushed files to the DocumentRoot.
Problem is that templates and configs mentioned above can be also edited by CMS and my pushes may overwrite these changes.

How do I configure Git and local and/or remote repositories in order to safely push my local edits to the site?

Comment: Depends on your intentions. I think the cleanest way would be to make `DocumentRoot` also a git repo so when a modification is done through the CMS it would result in a new commit each time. Then you could try to push your changes directly there.